# Http Get catch is not working in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a service.ts class with the following :

```
getData(username:string, password:string) {

    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('username', username);
    params.set('password', password);


    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.search = params;
    return  this._http.get(this._url,requestOptions).map((res:Response)=>res.status)
   .catch((error: any) => {
                if (error.status === 500) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                }
                else if (error.status === 400) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                }
                else if (error.status === 409) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                }
                else if (error.status === 406) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                }
            });
}
```

My component.ts class is :

```
    onCLick(myForm : NgForm) {
    this._service.getData(this.userName, this.password).subscribe(resData => this.formStatus = resData,
    resError => this.formStatus = resError); 
    if (this.formStatus === 400) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/Home');
    } else if (this.formStatus === 200) {
    console.log(this.formStatus );
    } else {
       console.log(this.formStatus );
    }
  }
```

Here on running the page, even though the response is an error with status = 400, while debugging it is not entering the **catch** block of **service.ts** initially (after the server hit), instead it moves to the **component.ts**, in the function *onClick()*and then after execution out there entering the catch block, which look weird for me. I expect the **catch** block to be executed and not the **return** statement as there is an error. 
P.S: **formStatus** in referring two-way binding from the form.

and thus the

```
if (this.formStatus === 400) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/Home');
    } else if (this.formStatus === 200) {
    console.log(this.formStatus );
    } else {
       console.log(this.formStatus );
    }
```

The above part of code is not working as the status is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you debugging? Place console.log to catch block.

I think it's not good practice to check condition right after async execution.

This part executes async:

```
this._service.getData(this.userName, this.password).subscribe(resData => this.formStatus = resData,
    resError => this.formStatus = resError);
```

And this part may not execute correctly, because `this.formStatus` may not initialize yet.

```
if (this.formStatus === 400) {
this.router.navigateByUrl('/Home');
} else if (this.formStatus === 200) {
console.log(this.formStatus );
} else {
   console.log(this.formStatus );
}
```

You have to check it inside error block.

Comment: You are right , but please do clarify the following for me : 
1. What is meant by async?
2. Could you please correct me in the code, I tried many ways ,but cant find a way through. If i add inside an error block, i may not be able to take care of the success scenario right?
I am new to angular 2 and so having these doubts.

Comment: When you do .subscribe (subscribing to observable) it executes asynchronous, and when next value emitted onSuccess or onError occurs. This code not blocking thread execution, that why next code to .subscribe executes immediately.
You need to handle http errors in onError block 400, 500, and success in onSuccess block.


`this._service.getData(this.userName, this.password).subscribe(resData => this.formStatus = resData, // this is success block
    resError => {
this.formStatus = resError;
//check error status here
});  // this is error block`

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, but
`onClick(loginForm : NgForm) {
    this._service.getData(this.userName, this.password).subscribe(
      resData => this.formStatus = resData,
    resError => { this.formStatus = resError
    if (this.formStatus === 400) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/Home');
    }
    });`

I changed this accordingly, but still when the debug point is inside the error block, this.formStatus is still not initialized, its value is undefined.
Kindly have a look

Comment: I think the problem is in `return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));`
is this your custom object? `Error` or it's standart es6 error?

Comment: I corrected it and its working now. Thank you very much :)